# PowerShell modify root site properties

Tags: powershell, iis-8.5

I need to set the serviceAutoStartProvider and serviceAutostartEnabled properties on some websites with powershell.

This cmdlet works on website with web application:

> Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\$websiteName\$webApplicationName -name serviceAutoStartEnabled -Value 'True'

With website without web application, I'm doing this

> Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\$websiteName -name serviceAutoStartEnabled -Value 'True'

But it doesn't work, I got this error

> Property serviceAutoStartEnabled is not found

When I check the applicationHost.config file of IIS, every website have a default webapplication, so, how can I set these properties on the root site ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I found this cmdlets

> Set-ItemProperty IIS:\Sites\$siteName -name applicationDefaults.serviceAutoStartEnabled -Value 'True'

And It's works :)